# How to use AtlasKit Editor with Next.js?

Tags: next.js, atlaskit

I'm trying to use AtlasKit with Next.js 8, but for some reason, there is a `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` error when attempting to build.

I think it's an issue with @atlaskit/editor-core not being properly preprocessed for ES6 (via webpack or babel, etc), but I'm not sure. Any ideas?

```
//Home.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import * as classnames from 'classnames';
import * as css from './Home.css';
import { Editor } from '@atlaskit/editor-core';

export const Home: React.FunctionComponent = props => (
  <div className={classnames('test', css.home)}>
    <Editor />
  </div>
);
```

I've created a repo to replicate the issue here: https://github.com/brandontle/nextjs-with-atlaskit

The file that uses AtlasKit Editor is ~/src/components/Home.tsx.